# how to remove KnockOutjs items when the quantity is set to 0?

Tags: knockout.js

I have a shopping cart where the item quantity can be changed by user. I want to remove the item from the cart when the quantity of the item is set to 0. Right now, I have if condition that makes the item disappear from the list when the quantity is set to 0, but if you look at the total items on the cart, the number does not change. How do I remove the item from the cart when the quantity is set to 0?

```
<!-- HTML Part -->
<div>
    <div> 
        <span><strong>Item</strong></span>  
        <span><strong>Price</strong></span>
        <span><strong>Quantity</strong></span>
        <span><strong>Subtotal</strong></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-bind='foreach:items'>
    <!-- ko if:qty()>0 -->
    <div> 
        <span data-bind='html: title'></span>  
        <span data-bind='text: price'></span>
        <span data-bind='visible: !editing(), text:formatted_qty'>&nbsp;</span>
        <input type='text' name='qty' data-bind='visible:editing, value:formatted_qty, hasFocus:editing' size="2"/> 
        <a href="#" data-bind='visible: !editing(), click:edit'>Edit Qty</a>
        <span data-bind='text:sub_total()'></span>
        <a href='#' data-bind='click: $parent.remove_item'>Remove</a>
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
<p>
<strong>Total Items</strong>: <span data-bind="text: total_items()"></span>
</p>

<!-- Javascipt Part -->

function item(id, title, price, qty) {
    var self = this;
    self.id = ko.observable(id);
    self.title = ko.observable(title);
    self.price = ko.observable(price);
    self.qty = ko.observable(qty);

    self.editing = ko.observable(false);
    self.edit = function () {
        self.editing(true);
    };
    self.formatted_qty = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            return self.qty();
        },
        write: function (value) {
            if (isNaN(value) || value.length < 1) {
                console.error('Invalid Quantity');
            } else {
                self.qty(value);
                console.info('Quantity changed');
            }
        },
        owner: self
    });

    self.sub_total = ko.computed(function () {
        var total = self.price() * self.qty();
        if (isNaN(total)) {
            return '-';
        }
        return total;
    }, self);
}

function vm() {
    var self = this;
    self.items = ko.observableArray([
    new item('1', 'Item1', 10, 1),
    new item('2', 'Item2', 20, 3),
    new item('3', 'Item3', 15, 1),
    new item('4', 'Item2', 25, 2),
    new item('5', 'Item2', 30, 6)
    ]);
    self.remove_item = function (item) {      
            self.items.remove(item);
    };
    self.total_items = ko.computed(function(){
        return self.items().length;       
    });
}
ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

Please see this jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/nm2hj9pn/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant do it via Knockout per se because Knockout is just computing over the underlying items collection as input but you could modify your compute total function as below or else use the removal code in response to another event:

```
 self.total_items = ko.computed(function(){
        for(var i=self.items().length-1;i>=0;i--)
        {
            var item = self.items()[i];
            if (item.qty()<=0)
            {
            self.items.remove(item);
            };
        };
        return self.items().length;       
    });
```

Comment: Thank you [rism](http://stackoverflow.com/users/70149/rism) for the answer. I used your approach and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of small changes makes this more knockout-like:

- use a computed called something like `filteredItems` if you want to exclude certain items (in your case, ones with `qty <= 0`).  Avoid doing this logic in the template itself as that mixes logic with presentation too much.
- avoid using `ko.observable` for properties that won't change (like the item price or title; in some cases these may change but in yours they don't, so keep it more efficient by making them plain properties: each observable adds dependency tracking overhead).

Fixed fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nm2hj9pn/20/

Relevant JS logic here:

```
function item(id, title, price, qty) {
    ...
    // don't need these to be observable as they don't change
    self.id = id;
    self.title = title;
    self.price = price;
    ...

function vm() {
    ...
    self.filteredItems = ko.computed(function(){
        return self.items().filter(function(item){
            return item.qty() > 0;
        });
    });
    ...
    self.total_items = ko.computed(function(){
        return self.filteredItems().length;
    });
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you [Milimetric](http://stackoverflow.com/users/180664/milimetric) for the sugesstions. I just started using KO, the tips you provided are really helpful.